# Android AOSP project import into eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, makefile, android-source

So, this is not like other problems. I have basically one question

Android project build system uses the Android.mk files.

Is there any eclipse plugin out there that parses through the mk files and allows me to load those projects into eclipse ? essentially import Android.mk file project...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can import the whole Android sources into eclipse. The instructions are [here](http://source.android.com/source/using-eclipse.html). Then you should make some modifications (for instance, include android-common_intermediates/javalib.jar instead of google-common_intermediates/javalib.jar) and you will have possibility to develop in eclipse.

Eclipse separates Android sources to several projects by itself(I think according to classpath entries). If you want to change this behavior you should look in this direction.

Comment: The problem is that the AOSP and the instruction here is not a Android project. How do one import it as a Android project. How do Google for example work with the Contacts app?

Comment: I do not understand your question.

Comment: Thanks for replying, the AOSP can be build under Unix with make. Additionally you can import it into Eclipse as you responded. This import is a "Java" project. I want to import it as a Android project and only for example the Contacts app. I have found no instructions doing this. Also I wonder how do Google really work when changing for example the Contacts app? Surely not in a Java project...

Comment: It's possible that they change the application as Java project, I do not see any difficulties to do this.

Comment: Im not sure I understand? It is a Java project. I want a Android project. Ahha maybe you mean it's Android and then they convert to Java for the AOSP?

Comment: Actually, now I develop (and change even AOSP applications) just in Eclipse. If I change just the code of one application I need to recompile only this one and check it.

Comment: And can you run it as an Android app in the device AVD Emulator from within Eclipse (Run As, Android Application)?

Comment: No. I make modifications, build the application as a part of AOSP and sync the result (or sometimes I reflash my device).

Comment: The link to instructions is broken, and I can't find any updated equivalent [here](http://source.android.com/source/). Likely this is an indication there's even less interest from Google in allowing this.

Answer (score 4):

If you have tried eclipse instructions at Android source site, you probably would know by now that it leaves lot of details to imagination.

One thing you need to keep in mind is that AOSP build doesn't work with eclipse. As long as you build your code from terminal and use eclipse to edit/browse/debug purposes, you will have more productive sessions.

The article at [Using Eclipse to browse/edit Android platform code](http://apienthusiast.blogspot.com/2014/06/using-eclipse-to-browse-and-edit-aosp.html) explains this in step by step.